# How to change background color of an eps file while converting it to jpeg or png

Tags: image-manipulation, ghostscript, eps, image-conversion

I am converting eps (Encapsulated PostScript) files to jpeg files with ghostscript. A sample command I use is:

```
gswin32.exe -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=100 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r600x600  -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dUseCIEColor  -dEPSCrop -sOutputFile=”a.jpeg” b.eps
```

The input eps files come with white backgrounds (I only have their clipping path). What I need to do is change this white background to another color in the output images, or it would be even better if I could make them transparent (output file format would be png). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never tried it myself but you should be able to convert your eps file into png by setting:

```
-sDEVICE=pngalpha
```

also the pngalpha device has a -dBackgroundColor option:

> -dBackgroundColor=16#RRGGBB (RGB color, default white = 16#ffffff) For
>   the pngalpha device only, set the
>   suggested background color in the PNG
>   bKGD chunk. When a program reading a
>   PNG file does not support alpha
>   transparency, the PNG library converts
>   the image using either a background
>   color if supplied by the program or
>   the bKGD chunk. One common web browser
>   has this problem, so when using  on a web page you
>   would need to use
>   -dBackgroundColor=16#CCCC00 when creating alpha transparent PNG images
>   for use on the page.

more details here: [Details of Ghostscript output devices](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/cvs/Devices.htm) see section 3.1. PNG file format

Answer (score 0):

After you've obtained your (white background) images from Ghostscript, you could use ImageMagick's `convert` or GraphicMagick's `gm convert` commands to change the white to transparent background:

`convert -background transparent my.png my_transp.png`